# Forgot my Gmail Password,alternate id is not accessible and no mobile No

Tags: account-management, google-account, password-recovery

I forgot my gmail password and my alternate id is also not accessible. I haven't provided my mobile number. Now am not able to access mail and facebook account. How can I reset my gmail password. I haven't used my account for about 6 months. I tried the normal rest process but didn't worked. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if none of the recovery options suit your situation, you may never regain access to your account. However, there is still the option of manually verifying your identity.

To begin, go to the google login page. Click "Need Help" then "Forgot password". Enter your email and click continue. If you are asked to enter the last password you remember, click "I don't know". Then click "Verify your identity" which is located under all of the other options. (It is a small link)
[image]

You will then be asked multiple questions which you must answer to the best of your ability. If you can provide enough accurate information, you will get your account back.

Hope this helps,

Adam